# Kotlin: Change the json property name depending on the @JsonView

Tags: java, serialization, kotlin, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to use Jackson to serialize the same DTO object in 2 different ways, depending on the `@JsonView`.

I want to use 2 different names for the same field. In one case I want to name the json property `myField` (just like the class field name), in the other I want it to be named `myInternalApiField`.

As a result I would like to see outcomes similar to the presented below:

Usage 1 (External API View):

```
{
    "myField": "value1",
    "myOtherField": "otherValue"
}
```

Usage 2 (Internal API View):

```
{
    "myInternalApiField": "value1",
    "myOtherField": "otherValue"
}
```

In my implementation in Java to achieve that I used the combination of custom getters, setters and `@JsonView` annotation as below:

```
public class CustomDTO {
        @JsonView(Views.ExternalApiView)
        private String myField;
        // Other fields here

        @JsonView(Views.InternalApiView)
        public String getMyInternalApiField() { return myField; }
        @JsonView(Views.InternalApiView)
        public void setMyInternalApiField(String value) { this.myField = value; }

        @JsonView(Views.ExternalApiView)
        public String getMyField() { return myField; }

        @JsonView(Views.ExternalApiView)
        public void setMyField(String value) { this.myField = value }
}
```

However I don't know how to properly achieve the same result in Kotlin.

I was thinking about using something like:

```
data class CustomDTO(
        @get:[JsonView(Views.ExternalApiView) JsonProperty("myField")]
        @get:[JsonView(Views.InternalApiView) JsonProperty("myInternalApiField")]
        @set:[JsonView(Views.InternalApiView) JsonProperty("myField")]
        @set:[JsonView(Views.InternalApiView) JsonProperty("myInternalApiField")]
        var myField: String,
        val myOtherField: String,
        val myDifferentField: String
)
```

But this is not allowed in Kotlin.

Do you have any suggestions how to utilize the `@JsonView` in Kotlin in the similar way as I did it in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
data class CustomDTO(
        @JsonView(ExternalApiView::class)
        var myField: String,
        val myOtherField: String,
        val myDifferentField: String
) {
    val myExternalField: String
        @JsonView(InternalApiView::class)
        get() {
            return myField
        }
}
```

It looks like there are ways that don't require creating computed properties in the DTO, like:

- Using [Jackson Mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205158/combine-jackson-jsonview-and-jsonproperty)
- Creating a [custom serializer](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers) for a particular invocation
- Combining a custom serializer with [custom annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646098/jackson-serialize-field-to-different-name)

But these have their own complexity, even if that complexity isn't in the DTO class. I'm not sure these are much more appealing to *me* but you could see if they appeal to you.

Comment: This seems to be a working solution, but won't it result in a new field in the CustomDTO class, visible also outside of the serialization/deserialization process? I am trying no to introduce new variables ;)

Comment: I don't think it's introducing more variables any more than the Java version you posted would -- the `val` in the kotlin version above is a derived value, there's no additional storage. It would be visible outside the serialization process, but so would `getMyInternalApiField` in the Java version, wouldn't it?

Comment: You have convinced me! Let me just wait a bit to see if any other suggested solutions are going to show up here and then I will accept your answer. 

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I do agree that it would be nice if there were a way to do this with annotations alone, although I don't know of a way to do it. ;)